# Collaboration between files using jumi in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5, jumi

I am a beginner php and joomla user. I have installed jumi component in joomla 2.5. I want to collaborate between pages but I don't know how to link between them. Can anyone please help me by explaining briefly.

Such as I have created a new file in jumi named "linked to another article" and the codes are explained below:

I have defined them:

```
defined("_JEXEC") OR die ("Restricted access");
```

I have created a link:

```
$linktext = "<Click> & you'll see";
```

After that I put the href:

```
<a href="FILE PATH"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($linktext);?>
```

After that I have created another file in jumi named "ABC" where I put `<?php echo"Hello World"?>`, how can I include the path of ABC file in the "FILE PATH" of my first file so that if I click on the first files link then it will redirect me to my ABC file and show "Hello World"?

I will be grateful for your kind reply.
Thanks.

Comment: could you please explian ?

Comment: I just edited my question and explained briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have 2 files in the jumi directory (components/com_jumi/files). **A.php** and **B.php**.

We don't want people to be able to access those files directly, so we place inside them the snippet

`defined("_JEXEC") OR die ("Restricted access");`

So far so good. Assuming that your website's URL is h**p://www.example.com, you'll get a

restricted access if you try any of the bellow:

h**p://www.example.com/components/com_jumi/files/A.php or

h**p://www.example.com/components/com_jumi/files/B.php.

This means that you cannot use those URLs to access for example **B.php** from **A.php**.

So here is a workaround:

1. Create 2 jumi applications from your administration panel, one for A.php (let's call it **Application_A**) and one for B.php (let's call it **Application_B**). I supose you have already done that.
2. Create a menu item of type Jumi application, point it to **Application_A** and use as its alias the **application_a**. From this point A.php its accesible as h**t://www.example.com/application_a
3. Create a **new Joomla menu** (you can call it hidden for clarity), and in that menu create a menu item of type Jumi application, point it to **Application B** and use as its alias the **application_b**. From this point B.php its accesible as h**t://www.example.com/application_b
4. So. whenever you want to access B.php from A.php you can do it simply as

   `<a href="application_b">Go to B</a>`